# Code works in a console application, but does not work when running in windows service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-services

I wrote a windows service. Part of the code works : (example from msdn)

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        file = new StreamWriter(new FileStream("MyFirstService.log",
                          System.IO.FileMode.Append));
        this.file.WriteLine("MyFirstService стартовал");
        this.file.Flush(); 
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(WatchProcess));
        thread.Start();
    }
```

I am adding this code :

```
private void WatchProcess()
    {
            var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", true);
            key.SetValue("dWatch", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            System.IO.FileSystemWatcher fWatcher;
            fWatcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
            fWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            fWatcher.Path = @"C:\Windows";
            fWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
            fWatcher.NotifyFilter = System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastAccess | System.IO.NotifyFilters.LastWrite | System.IO.NotifyFilters.FileName | System.IO.NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
            fWatcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            fWatcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            fWatcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            fWatcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
            fWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WatcherChangeTypes wtc = e.ChangeType;
        string str = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(str);
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + wtc.ToString());
    }


    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(str);
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
    }
```

The code above works when I run it in console application, but in windows service it does not work. And service automatically stops after 30 seconds.

Comment: where does it fails? have you tried to run the service under your account?

Comment: I set the Account property to LocalSystem. and instal service as administrator. there were no errors, create a text file and run, the entry "Myfirstservice is start" was made. but service dont watch the filesystem

Comment: try to run it as your account - under service control

Comment: Are you keeping your service alive? I'm just making sure that you have an endless loop somewhere in the software. Otherwise the service will stop when it is done creating the thread(which then also stops).

Comment: i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        file = new StreamWriter("C:\\Public\\fswThread." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".txt");
        System.IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = @"C:\Windows";
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                             | NotifyFilters.FileName   | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler( OnChanged );
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        file.Close();
    }

    private void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        file.WriteLine( "C: " + e.FullPath );
        file.AutoFlush = true;

        if (file.BaseStream.Length > 100)
        {
            file.Flush();
            file.Close();
            file = new StreamWriter("C:\\Public\\fswThread." + DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString() + ".txt");
        }


    }
```